# Name of the spinner event's view

Tags: android

what is the name of this view.[link text](http://img169.imageshack.us/i/picture1y.jpg/)

Comment: when we click a spinner in a application,we got a screen(http://img169.imageshack.us/i/picture1y.jpg/ )....i want to know the name of the screen

Answer (score 3):

There is no "name" of that screen per se -- it is just the result of clicking on a `Spinner`.

You can achieve a similar look, though, via an `AlertDialog`.